# Using ADB2C and MS Graph to login a user via the SDK or REST API and bypass webviews

Tags: oauth, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am using ADB2C with a mobile app I am developing. We are using the WebViews to perform the authentication and this works fine.

I ideally want to get away from web views to give the user a more native experience, while still using ADB2C in the backend.

Using the graph SDK, I can pretty much do every task except sign in a user. There doesnt seem to be a way to sign the user in and get an Authentication token. I'm assuming this is by design (OAuth etc), but is there any work around?

(Note, I would need the same facility using it on a web app too)

Comment: Have you checked the ROPC flow? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc?tabs=applications Do note you won't be able to use multi-factor authentication if you use this flow.

Comment: Yeh I did look at that but they seem to be frowning on it quite heavily. There also doesn't seem to be any clear examples of using this on a web app.

Comment: Well, it exists in the spec mainly to allow legacy applications a migration path. Modern federated authentication uses HTTP redirects quite a lot which isn't always the best thing for mobile apps.

Comment: Sure. Do you know if this would be possible to use with a web app? I guess you would somehow need to set and manage the AspNet identity cookie?

Comment: If it's a Web app, I always use the standard redirect-based flows there. Probably no technical reason you couldn't use ROPC there as well.

Comment: The reason seems to be the amount of plumbing required for it to work. Its probably easier creating a custom policy rather than doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a whole ton of ms code examples for various platforms to use, have you checked these out?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/code-samples
they include examples for native, mobile, and webapps and all use either msal or purpose built libraries. is this not an option?

Comment: Yes they do, but they all require the OAuth web view. Seems like ROPC flow is the only way to avoid this but obviously has its downsides so I think the webview is the only way going forward.